# Understanding IgniteDataStreamer: ordering and buffering

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

I'm using `IgniteDataStreamer` with `allowOverwrite` to load continious data.

Question 1.
From javadoc:

> Note that streamer will stream data concurrently by multiple internal threads, so the data may get to remote nodes in different order from which it was added to the streamer.

Reordering is not acceptable in my case. Will `perNodeParallelOperations` set to `1` guarantee keeping order of `addData` calls? There is a number of caches being simultaneously loaded with `IgniteDataStreamer`, so Ignite server node threads will all be utilized anyway.

Question 2.
My streaming application could hang for a couple of seconds due to GC pause. I want to avoid cache loading pause at that moments and keep high average cache writing speed. Is iy possible to configure `IgniteDataStreamer` to keep (bounded) queue of incoming batches on server node, that would be consumed while streaming (client) app hangs? See question 1, queue should be consumed sequentially. It's OK to utilize some heap for it.

Question 3.
`perNodeBufferSize` javadoc:

> This setting controls the size of internal per-node buffer before buffered data is sent to remote node

According to javadoc, data transfer is triggered by `tryFlush` / `flush` / `autoFlush`, so how does it correlate with `perNodeBufferSize` limitation? Would flush be ignored if there is less than `perNodeBufferSize` messages (I hope no)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend trying to avoid reordering in `DataStreamer`, but if you absolutely need to do that, you will also need to set **data streamer pool size** to 1 on server nodes. If it's larger then data is split into stripes and not sent sequentially.

DataStreamer is designed for throughput, not latency. So there's not much you can do here. Increasing `perThreadBufferSize`, perhaps?

Data transfer is automatically started when perThreadBufferSize is reached for any stripe.

Comment: My input is an ordered stream of entities, possibly with duplicated keys. I want to keep resulting state of that stream in Ignite. Looks like very common case. Reordering of writes would lead to random cache state, it's defenetly not what I want. Does setting data streamer pool size to 1 mean all caches would be written in single thread? If so, it looks to be slow in total. What if I load cache with sequental `putAll` calls? Would order be guaranteed?

Comment: You can use StreamReciever to resolve conflicts, so that "correct" value will always come on top. PutAll should be OK, just make sure to use `TreeMap`.